# Selecting the first radio button within a function

Tags: jquery, select, filter, radio-button, onchange

I'm using the following radio buttons to filter a series of items:

```
<label>Numbers</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="number" value="1">1<br/>
<input type="radio" name="number" value="2">2<br/>
<label>Letters</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="letter" value="a">a<br/>
<input type="radio" name="letter" value="b">b
```

The item markup looks like this:

```
<ul class="all-options">
    <li class="1 a">
         <h3>Price</h3>
         <h2>$1000</h2>
    </li>
    <li class="1 b">
         <h3>Price</h3>
         <h2>$1500</h2>
    </li>
    <li class="2 a">
         <h3>Price</h3>
         <h2>$1200</h2>
    </li>
    <li class="2 b">
         <h3>Price</h3>
         <h2>$1300</h2>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I'm using this function to filter based on change events:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function () {
        var number = $("[name='number']:checked").val();
        var letter = $("[name='letter']:checked").val();
        $("li").hide();
        $("li").filter(function (index) {
        return $(this).hasClass(number) && $(this).hasClass(letter);
        }).show();
    });
});
```

That's all working great except for one thing: I'd like the first radio buttons in each category (number & letter) to be automatically selected when the page is loaded. And, I'd like these selections to be reflected in the filter. So, in this case for example, on page load, I'd like to be seeing the item with the classes 1 & a.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the checked attribute, like so:

```
<label>Numbers</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="number" value="1" checked>1<br/>
<input type="radio" name="number" value="2">2<br/>
<label>Letters</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="letter" value="a" checked>a<br/>
<input type="radio" name="letter" value="b">b
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can do this dynamically? That way the first radio button will always be selected, no matter what the value. And, that still doesn't activate the filter because it's not triggering a change.